# Why is this user id not coming out of req.user;

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, authorization

This is my code for getting user info

```
router.post("/getuser", fetchuser, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    userId = req.user.id;
    const user = await User.findById(userId).select("-password");
    res.send(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});
```

and this is the code for middleware fetchuser

```
const fetchuser = async (req, res, next) => {
const token = req.header('auth-token');
if (!token) {
    res.status(401).send({ error: "Please authenticate using a valid token" })
}
try {
    const data = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
    console.log(data);
    req.user = data.user;
    next();
} catch (error) {
    res.status(401).send({ error: "Please authenticate using a valid token" })
}
};
```

I am getting the user id in console.log but when I try to get the user id in the router.post  then I am not able to get the user Info.
Here is the result I am getting.

```
Server is running on port 5000
Connected to database
{ id: '61e98c45a9d8818292b38505', iat: 1642743501 }
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

Please can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    router.post("/getuser", fetchuser, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const params = JSON.parse(req)
    userId = params.id;
    const user = await User.findById(userId).select("-password");
    res.send(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});
```

Comment: it is showing the following error "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

Comment: show me the console.log(req)

Comment: the response coming from jwt.verify in fetchuser middleware is not a string. It is clearly showing as object when I try to log on console.

Comment: Server is running on port 5000
Connected to database
{ id: '61e98c45a9d8818292b38505', iat: 1642736804 }
Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: oh there is no req.user try with console.log(typeof req)

Comment: is it possible for you to help as I share my screen

Comment: tell me your anydesk

Comment: 552326259 this is my anydesk id

Comment: i hope your problem solved

Comment: yes!.. Thanks to you man

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine , you just have to change this line on fetchuser middleware

`req.user = data.user`

to

`req.user = data`

and your code work as expected..

Answer (score 0):

add file: src/types/express/index.d.ts

content:

```
declare namespace Express {
    interface Request {
        user: {
            id: string;
        };
    }
}
```